# Generate list of days for each employee

Tags: python, pandas

EDIT: [This solution worked for me](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69194912/4046632)

I have the following dataframe in Python:

| Name | days | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EMP1 | 15 | 8/8/22 | 8/26/22 |
| EMP2 | 3 | 6/9/22 | 6/13/22 |
| EMP3 | 5 | 8/22/22 | 8/26/22 |
| EMP3 | 5 | 8/1/22 | 8/5/22 |
| EMP3 | 6 | 6/17/22 | 6/24/22 |
| EMP4 | 4.5 | 7/18/22 | 7/22/22 |
| EMP5 | 5 | 7/18/22 | 7/22/22 |
| EMP6 | 5 | 8/15/22 | 8/19/22 |
| EMP7 | 9 | 8/22/22 | 9/2/22 |

I need to generate the list of dates between the start and end date for each row whilst keeping the employee name . Is this simple to do in python? Really struggling to get it to do it by row .

desired output (list each day between start and end date and employees name):

| Name | date |
| --- | --- |
| EMP1 | 8/8/22 |
| EMP1 | 8/9/22 |
| EMP1 | 8/10/22 |
| EMP1 | 8/11/22 |
| EMP1 | 8/12/22 |
| EMP1 | 8/13/22 |
| EMP1 | 8/14/22 |
| EMP1 | 8/15/22 |

Comment: could you explain what mean _I have the following table in Python_?

Comment: a dataframe sorry

Comment: show us your desired output as well

Comment: You say that you're struggling.  Could we see what you've attempted so far and how it hasn't worked?

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/4046632)

Comment: @DanielWalker I can only do a simple calculation for the start - end date and list each date. Not sure how to do it for each row, or employee

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/q/69194912/4046632

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, convert the start date ,enddate to date range then explode using that
columns :

```
df['Date'] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(start=x['Start Date'], end=x['End Date']), axis=1)
output = df.explode('Date').drop(columns = ['days','Start Date','End Date'])
```

output :

```
>>
    Name       Date
0   EMP1 2022-08-08
0   EMP1 2022-08-09
0   EMP1 2022-08-10
0   EMP1 2022-08-11
0   EMP1 2022-08-12
..   ...        ...
8   EMP7 2022-08-29
8   EMP7 2022-08-30
8   EMP7 2022-08-31
8   EMP7 2022-09-01
8   EMP7 2022-09-02

[69 rows x 2 columns]
```